# Java - How do i make a string read and count amounts in another string (

Tags: java, string, counter

I'm having trouble activating my counter++. So far s2 is able to read s1, but cannot count amount of occurrences. Any help would be appreciated. (I realize that I am working in the wrong string, but it helps me to create the solution here first and then send it to a second string, is this poor logic?)

Sorry for the dumb question I am very new at programming

//i need a scanner that reads what i write that scanner should count
occurrences of a char another scanner declared scanner a would ask " write something" string s. = nextline etc new scanner asks for a letter string s1 = next line blb that input = something int count = StringUtils.countMatches(s1); System.out.print(amount ) i
//

```
public class Task07 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("write something");
        String text = s1.nextLine(); //reads user input value

        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(System.in);  // missing smth that limits length of s2  
        System.out.println("geb a letter");
        String letter = s2.nextLine();
        int counter = 0;
        boolean found;
        found = text.contains(letter);
        if (found == true) {
            counter++;
        } else {

            System.out.println(counter);
        }
    // could use counter from 6 here but need a way to tell counter 
        // that it should add +1 for every time something occurs in 
        // the other scanner

        /*
            Problems: text recognizer is boolean only
             - doesnt activate counter
             - doesnt activate counter based on X times occurence           
            - doesnt limit "letter" to only one char
            - 

         */
    }

}
```

Comment: I should add that part of the assignment is to make this happen in another method, I was planning to do this after i fixed the counter.

Comment: Don't make scanner s2. What about grabbing the first character from letter or do you really want to make the user only enter one letter?

Comment: I want the user to enter 'something', and then be able to check for the amount of times 'a' happened in 'something'

Answer (score 1):

Basically a loop is the simple way to count character occurrences in a string. You would use something like

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    if (text.charAt(i) == letter.charAt(0)) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: charAt is a char, and letter is a string. Maybe include letter.charAt(0)?

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was trying to do,  I understand boolean was the wrong approach. Can you explain this?
(text.charAt(i) == letter.charAt(0))

Comment: charAt(int index) is a method on the String class which returns the character at the index location of the string object it is invoked on. The indices start at 0, just like the indices of an Array. So the loop traverses the text string one character at a time, and compares that character to the wanted letter. As matt pointed out, since letter is also a string and not a character, we need to use letter.charAt(0) for the comparison (the first char of the string letter).